# Unable to get proper output from regex

Tags: php, regex

Here's my regex code :

```
Name:<\/h5>.*?<div class="info-name">(.*?)(<a|<\/div|\|)
```

Here's the content :

```
<h5>Name:</h5>
<div class="info-name">
Josh Taguibao
</div><a class="t0 profile" >Click to view Profile</a>
```

I am able to get my output, which is

```
Josh Taguibao
```

However, if the content changes with something like this :

```
<h5>Name:</h5>
<div class="info-name">
Josh <a href="#tagclan">Taguibao</a>
</div><a class="t0 profile" >Click to view Profile</a>
```

I will only be able to get ***Josh*** instead of the whole name.

May I ask on what to add on my code?

Comment: That's exactly what your regex tells
it gets what after "info-name"> until it finds <a or <div which comes first.
I suggest you remove **<a** part.
You may go into another problem that <a href="#tagclan"> will be in the output, You can just remove it.

Comment: OMG! Thank you <3 Did not thought of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an html parser (which the SO community strongly urges at every chance), you can just match and strip the tags:

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28eeb68f8f82f961d46adeea34616fd3077afe39))  ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wairoP/1))

```
$string='<h5>Name:</h5>
<div class="info-name">
Josh <a href="#tagclan">Taguibao</a>
</div><a class="t0 profile" >Click to view Profile</a>';

echo preg_match('~Name:</h5>.*?<div class="info-name">\s*\K.*?(?=\s*</div|\s*\|)~s',$string,$out)?strip_tags($out[0]):'fail';
```

Output:

```
Josh Taguibao
```

*Notes:

- `~` is used as the pattern delimiter so that the `/`s in the pattern don't need to be escaped.
- `\K` in the pattern means: "start the fullstring match from here"
- `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead, which is used to halt the fullstring match before matching a newline followed by `</div` or `|`  (normally I would write `(?=\s(?:</div>|\|))` but it was actually fewer steps the verbose way)
- The `s` modifier/flag at the end of the pattern permits the `.` (dots) to additionally match new lines.

---

Now, DomDocument is not my strong suit, but I slapped together this snippet that will work on your sample text. ([DomDocument Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f9a89c86d215df8118b1138ebb84c016115ab20))

```
$html='<h5>Name:</h5>
<div class="info-name">
Josh <a href="#tagclan">Taguibao</a>
</div><a class="t0 profile" >Click to view Profile</a>';

$dom=new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$name=$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue; // or ->textContent
echo trim($name);
// same output as regex method
```

`nodeValue` and `textContent` are effectively the same (for this case anyhow) in that they both return the tag-free text from the div element.

> [Manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent): **textContent** The text content of this node and its descendants.

---

Or if you need to isolate the first occurring element which has the class `info-name`, then you can use XPath: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/goHEB))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
var_export(
    trim(
        (new DOMXPath($dom))
        ->query('//*[@class="info-name"]')
        ->item(0)
        ->nodeValue
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML is structured data. This means there are tools available to parse it. Regex is not the tool for this job.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: This answer is more of a link-only comment than an answer.